# Form.DesktopBounds.Width seems to be off by 10 pixels. How to determine correct form width?

Tags: c#, winforms

When accessing the Form.DesktopBounds.Width property it seems to be off by 10 pixels.  It also seems that the window border is 5 pixels on each side.  How can I determine the correct form width, including the border around the form.

Comment: Do you get different results with `Form.Width`?

Comment: If you can make it 6 pixels instead of 10 then there's an explanation for it.

Comment: What is the value of your form's `FormBorderStyle` property?

Comment: This is dependent upon the window border style.

Comment: This is dependent upon the window border style.  If the window has a border of None, then the Bounds are the same as the window size.  But with the default Fixed Single border style, indeed the bounds are 5 pixels larger than the display area on the right, left, and bottom.  One of these pixels, I think, is the thin blue border.  The other 4 are a transparent area.  If such a form is displayed on your desktop, you can select it by clicking on the desktop NEAR the right side of the form.  Seem like a strange design choice, but not unusual for Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds.aspx), if you want to get the size and location of the control *including* its nonclient elements, you just want to use `Form.Bounds`.  In the case of width, that would be `Form.Bounds.Width`.

I believe my comment suggestion of `Form.Width` will work as well, since `Top`, `Left`, `Width`, and `Height` all come from the `Bounds` themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.

I get the "off by 10" numbers from `Form.Height` and from `Form.Bounds.Height`.  The height values are correct on Windows XP, but off by 10 on Windows 7.  (`Width` values are also off.)

When the `FormBorderStyle` is `Sizable` then the values are correct.  But when it is `FixedToolWindow` I get the off-by-10 values.